# How to get pdf file while printing report in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have used this code but not working returning empty PDF file in odoo 10

```
self.env['report'].sudo().get_pdf(self, 'equipment_management.report_gatepass')
```

.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <openerp>
    <data>


<report id="equipment_action"
      model="calibration.details"
      string="Gatepass "
      report_type="qweb-pdf"
      name="equipment_management.report_gatepass"
      file="equipment_management.report_gatepass"
      />

  <record id="paperformats" model="report.paperformat">
      <field name="name">European A4 low margins</field>
      <field name="default" eval="True" />
      <field name="format">A4</field>
      <field name="page_height">0</field>
      <field name="page_width">0</field>
      <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
      <field name="margin_top">20</field>
      <field name="margin_bottom">20</field>
      <field name="margin_left">20</field>
      <field name="margin_right">20</field>
      <field name="header_line" eval="False" />
      <field name="header_spacing">10</field>
      <field name="dpi">90</field>
  </record>

  <record id="equipment_management.equipment_action" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
      <field name="paperformat_id" ref="equipment_management.paperformats" />
  </record>
  <template id="report_gatepass">
      <t t-call="report.html_container">
      <t t-set="counter" t-value="001"/>
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <div class="page">
                <style>
                    .box{
                    background: black;
                    max-width: 250px;
                    text-align:center;
                    color:white;}
                </style>
                <div class="row">
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="border:1px solid black">
                        <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black">
                            <td width="20%" valign="top" align="center" padding="15px">
                                <img t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % res_company.logo" height="100px" width="90px" />
                            </td>
                            <td width= "80%">
                                <div style="font-size:18px;"><center><b><t t-if="res_company.name" t-esc="res_company.name"/></b></center></div>
                                <div style="font-size:12px;"><center><t t-if="res_company.rml_header1" t-esc="res_company.rml_header1"/></center></div>
                                <div style="font-size:12px"><center><t t-if="res_company.street" t-esc ="res_company.street"/>  <t t-if="res_company.street2" t-esc ="res_company.street2"/>  <t t-if="res_company.state_id" t-esc ="res_company.state_id.name"/>  <t t-if="res_company.country_id" t-esc ="res_company.country_id.name"/></center></div>
                                <div style="font-size:12px"><center>Tel No.<t t-if="res_company.phone" t-esc ="res_company.phone"/>,  Fax<t t-if="res_company.fax" t-esc ="res_company.fax"/>,  Email <t t-if="res_company.email" t-esc ="res_company.email"/>,  Website <t t-if="res_company.website" t-esc ="res_company.website"/></center></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" width="100%" style="font-size:24px"><center><div class="box"><strong>GATEPASS</strong></div></center></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black">
                            <td colspan="2" width="100%" style="font-size:14px"><center><strong>(NIWE-Returnable Material)</strong></center></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="25%" style="font-size:14px;line-height:300%;"><center><strong>Reference No.:</strong></center></td>
                                        <td width="25%" style="font-size:14px;line-height:300%;text-align:left;"><strong><t t-esc="o.name"/></strong></td>
                                        <td width="25%" style="font-size:14px;line-height:300%;"><center><strong>Date:</strong></center></td>
                                        <td width="25%" style="font-size:14px;line-height:300%;text-align:left"><strong><span t-field="o.date" t-field-options='{"format": "dd-MM-y"}'/></strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>   
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="font-size:12px">
                                    <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black;height:50px;">
                                        <td width="5%" style="text-align:center;border-right:1px solid black">1</td>
                                        <td width="53%" style="padding-left:5px;border-right:1px solid black">Name and Designation of the Person taking the Material</td>
                                        <td width="42%" style="padding-left:5px"><t t-if="o.responsible_person.name" t-esc="o.responsible_person.name"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black;height:60px;">                                         
                                        <td width="5%" style="text-align:center;border-right:1px solid black">2</td>
                                        <td width="53%" style="padding-left:5px;border-right:1px solid black">Address of supplier taking material out of NIWE Campus(with phone No.)</td>
                                        <td width="42%" style="padding-left:5px">
                                        <div style="font-size:12px"><t t-if="o.responsible_person.street" t-esc ="o.responsible_person.street"/></div> 
                                        <div><t t-if="o.responsible_person.street2" t-esc ="o.responsible_person.street2"/></div>
                                        <div><t t-if="o.responsible_person.state_id" t-esc ="o.responsible_person.state_id.name"/> </div> 
                                        <div><t t-if="o.responsible_person.country_id" t-esc ="o.responsible_person.country_id.name"/></div>
                                        <div style="font-size:12px"><t t-if="o.responsible_person.phone" t-esc ="o.responsible_person.phone"/></div> 
                                        <div><t t-if="o.responsible_person.mobile" t-esc ="o.responsible_person.mobile"/></div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black;height:60px;">
                                        <td width="5%" style="text-align:center;border-right:1px solid black">3</td>
                                        <td width="53%" style="padding-left:5px;border-right:1px solid black">Description of items with its serial Number and Quantity etc.,</td>
                                        <td width="42%" style="padding-left:5px">
                                            <div><b>Name:</b><t t-if="o.instrument.name" t-esc="o.instrument.name"/></div>
                                            <div><b>Serial No:</b><t t-if="o.serial" t-esc="o.serial"/></div> 
                                            <div><b>Description:</b><t t-if="o.instrument.description" t-esc="o.instrument.description"/></div> 
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black;height:60px;">
                                        <td width="5%" style="text-align:center;border-right:1px solid black">4</td>
                                        <td width="53%" style="padding-left:5px;border-right:1px solid black">Purpose for which the Material(s) in/are being taken out</td>
                                        <td width="42%" style="padding-left:5px"><t t-if="o.purpose" t-esc="o.purpose"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black;height:60px;">
                                        <td width="5%" style="text-align:center;border-right:1px solid black">5</td>
                                        <td width="53%" style="padding-left:5px;border-right:1px solid black">Probable date of return of Material if any</td>
                                        <td width="42%" style="padding-left:5px"><t t-if="o.date_of_return"><span t-field="o.date_of_return" t-field-options='{"format": "dd-MM-y"}'/></t></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black;height:60px;">
                                        <td width="5%" style="text-align:center;border-right:1px solid black">6</td>
                                        <td width="53%" style="padding-left:5px;border-right:1px solid black">NIWE-officer responsible for inspection Returning the Material</td>
                                        <td width="42%" style="padding-left:5px"><t t-if="o.officer.name" t-esc="o.officer.name"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="height:60px;">
                                        <td width="5%" style="text-align:center;border-right:1px solid black">7</td>
                                        <td width="53%" style="padding-left:5px;border-right:1px solid black">Any other Informations</td>
                                        <td width="42%" style="padding-left:5px"><t t-if="o.other_info" t-esc="o.other_info"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table style="font-size:12px" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="35%" style="text-align:left"><span><div>Signature of the person taking the</div>
                            <div>Material out NIWE Campus</div></span></td>
                            <td width="35%"><span><div>Signature of the Officer/Material</div><div style="text-align:center">Indenter</div></span></td>
                            <td width="30%" style="text-align:right">Signature of Head/Project Leader</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table style="font-size:12px" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50%" style="text-align:left">Authorized Signatory</td>
                            <td width="50%" style="text-align:right"><span>Signature of Security Officer/Security 
                            <div>Guard on duty in NIWE</div></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
      </t>
  </template>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: can you post the full code?

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax:

```
pdf = request.env['report'].sudo().get_pdf([sale_order_id], 'sale.report_saleorder', data=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the report format of Odoo reports are in PDF, I don't know why your specifically asking for pdf file while printing. The below given is a sample code for attaching PDF file of sale_order report as attachment to the order/quotation using `.get_pdf`.

Example:

```
@api.multi
    def print_quotation(self):
        for order in self:
            result = self.env['report'].sudo().get_pdf([order.id], 'sale.report_saleorder')
            return self.env['ir.attachment'].create({
            'name': 'Sample',
            'type': 'binary',
            'datas': base64.encodestring(result),
            'res_model': 'sale.order',
            'res_id': order.id,
            'mimetype': 'application/x-pdf'
        })
```

Openerp has changed to Odoo. So please change the below section in your code if you are using Odoo 10.0:

```
<openerp>
    <data>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

to

```
<odoo>
    <data>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

Hope this may help you !

Comment: this method also returning empty file

Comment: can you edit your question and add the full code of what you have done so far. the above code I have tested in my own instance and its working.

Comment: give me you mail id , i will send it

Comment: It will will be fine if you post here, may be some one else other than me can also help you. just post the function not the entire module. Or add it in the github if you have long code.

Comment: please this is my post  in odoo forum  https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-get-pdf-file-while-printing-report-in-odoo-10-122146